# Display loading indicator while amp-list loads the content

Tags: progress-bar, amp-html

If an [amp-list](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list) takes more than, X seconds to fetch the content from the endpoint, how can I display a spinner in the meantime? The spinner should not be displayed unnecessarily if X is lower than 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the AMP runtime does display a loading indicator, consisting of three moving dots, even if the response takes as little as 0.1 seconds to load. The loading indicator can be customized via the `amp-active` class, as shown in the [Custom Loading Indicators sample](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/custom_loading_indicators/):

[image: AMP Custom Loading Indicator]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Placeholder and Fallback](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/placeholders) to modify it.
Or by adding the `noloading` Attribute you can hide the loading indicator.